# View Binding with 2 possible layouts, assign binding variable to 2 generated binding classes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewbinding

**Desired functionality:**

I have an Activity that has a value received from backend which indicates to use either one of two layouts. Let's call this value *layoutType* and let's assume for simplicity in this example code below that we don't care how it will be assigned. Thus, I have two layout xml files, let's call them *layout1.xml* & *layout2.xml*.

**Implementation:**
I'd like to use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#java). I've created a variable of type *ViewBinding* and I tried assigning to it either a *Layout1Binding* or a *Layout2Binding*. A summary of this logic in pseudocode is this:

```
 private ViewBinding binding;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     if(layoutType == 1){
         binding = Layout1Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
     } else {
         binding = Layout2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
     }
     setContentView(binding.getRoot());
 }
```

**Result:** Of course, this doesn't work and variable *binding* appears to have no inner children that can be referenced. Also, of course if I convert the variable's type to *Layout1Binding* and *layoutType* equals 1, then I can use it correctly. Same goes if I use *Layout2Binding* and *layoutType* is not equal to 1. All these make sense, since ViewBinding is just an Interface implemented by the generated classes *Layout1Binding* & *Layout2Binding*.

**Question:** How can I achieve the above desired behaviour by using only one binding variable which can be assigned to two different generated classes? Is there any other alternative way?

Comment: You have to either write an adapter that will wrap and accept both bindings types while exposing "common" fields or create a generic activity/fragment that have different binding type.

Comment: @Pawel could you please provide a relevant code/pseudocode sample that demonstrates this logic? I don't have an adapter, so I'm more interested in your second suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how I used an adapter for a custom view that uses three layouts. *In my case, most views in the different layout files had common IDs.*

#### Define your binding adapter class

```
class MyCustomViewBindingAdapter(
    b1: Layout1Binding?,
    b2: Layout2Binding?,
    b3: Layout3Binding?
) {

    val text =
        b1?.myTextView
            ?: b2?.myTextView
            ?: b3?.myTextView

    val badgeText = b3?.myBadgeTextView
}
```

#### Create a binding variable

```
private lateinit var binding: MyCustomViewBindingAdapter
```

#### Create a method to get the binding adapter

```
private fun getBinding(layoutType: Int): MyCustomViewBindingAdapter {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    return when(layoutType) {
        TEXT_ONLY -> {
            val textBinding = Layout1Binding.inflate(inflater, this, true)
            MyCustomViewBindingAdapter(textBinding, null, null)
        }
        IMAGE_AND_TEXT -> {
            val imageTextBinding = Layout2Binding.inflate(inflater, this, true)
            MyCustomViewBindingAdapter(null, imageTextBinding, null)
        }
        TEXT_AND_BADGE -> {
            val textBadgeBinding = Layout3Binding.inflate(inflater, this, true)
            MyCustomViewBindingAdapter(null, null, textBadgeBinding)
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
    }
}
```

#### Be sure to initialize the binding before using it

```
binding = getBinding(layoutType)
```