# Manage single Databinding object when conditional multiple layouts apply to single activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, layout, data-binding

Now I am working on a project in which I have to use multiple layouts in single  activity. Let me describe with example

For example there is an activity called **"DashboardActivity"** and I have to create 4 layout for this activity.

If there is **flowId=1** from the server I have to apply **activity_dashboard_layout_flow_one**. Same as like for **flowId=2/3/4**. I have different layout for all flows like **activity_dashboard_layout_flow_two** , **activity_dashboard_layout_flow_three** , **activity_dashboard_layout_flow_four** etc

Now I am using **databinding** in my project so simple all layout files generate Binding files. So there is different binding objects in my activity. But I want to use and manage only one binding object to access views from XML files.

So please suggest me how to handle Databinding in this situation. And what is the efficient way to do this in kotlin with databinding

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend moving them into fragments and push the desired fragment onto the activity once you have the request response.

This way you can handle each layout / binding individually on each fragment and there won't be any mixup.

Comment: @Brandon If I do this I have to do same functionality in all these fragments. Here Functionality is same in my case in single activity.. Functionality means api calling, views click and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After done some r&d I do the one solution that set binding object as **Any** type. Theme wise condition to set root layout and make extension functions of all views that return particular view from available 4 binding.

And today I found similar question with similar solution to my solution but this given solution is in better manner than my solution. check out following link

[View Binding with 2 possible layouts, assign binding variable to 2 generated binding classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214318/view-binding-with-2-possible-layouts-assign-binding-variable-to-2-generated-bin)