# How to propertly include layout in to the main layout to store all data in one data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I have three different blocks in my application. I'm trying to make a data binding.

Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to bind at least two layouts together.

This is part of my layout that I have to include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="textfieldview"
            type="red.button.flipper_navigator.ui_logic.MainScreenLogic" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        ........

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:text="@={textfieldview.link}"
                android:id="@+id/link"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:hint="@string/maps_link"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:minHeight="35dp"
                android:maxHeight="70dp"
                android:importantForAutofill="no">
                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>


        </TableRow>


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

this is where I'm including it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainview"
            type="red.button.flipper_navigator.ui_logic.MainScreenLogic" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MainScreen">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/flip_bar"
        layout="@layout/flip_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"></include>

<!--this part where i'm including my important layout right now. -->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/text_field"
        layout="@layout/text_field"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flip_bar">
</include>

<!--part ends -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generate"
        android:onClick="@{mainview::generateBt}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="320sp"
        android:text="generate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="315sp"
        android:text="Start\n Navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    </Button>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

this is my main file code:

```
package red.button.flipper_navigator.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import red.button.flipper_navigator.ui_logic.MainScreenLogic
import red.button.flipper_navigator.R
import red.button.flipper_navigator.databinding.ScreenMainBinding
import red.button.flipper_navigator.databinding.TextFieldBinding

//import red.button.flipper_navigator.databinding.TextFieldBinding



class MainScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding: ScreenMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.screen_main)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainScreenLogic::class.java]
        val exampleBinding: TextFieldBinding = TextFieldBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.mainview = viewModel
        exampleBinding.textfieldview = viewModel


    }
}
```

I'm trying to insert all my binding data into MainScreenLogic file using `ViewModelProvider`

I don't really understand what's wrong because it's been the 3 day, I'm trying, but nothing actually working.

This is MainScreenLogic file:

```
package red.button.flipper_navigator.ui_logic

import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel


class MainScreenLogic() : ViewModel() {
    var link: String = ""
    //val route = inputs(link)
    fun generateBt(view: View) {
        if (link == "ee") {
            Log.d("button", "ok")
        }
    }
}
```

Link variable is always empty.

I just need to pass data from EditText to the variable, but I need to group everything in one layout using include or merge.

I tried to google first, of course, found something, but didn't manage to make it works.

Links that i tried:

[View Binding - How do I get a binding for included layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730127/view-binding-how-do-i-get-a-binding-for-included-layouts)

https://medium.com/@elia.maracani/android-data-binding-passing-a-variable-to-an-include-d-layout-3567099b58f

[View Binding with 2 possible layouts, assign binding variable to 2 generated binding classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214318/view-binding-with-2-possible-layouts-assign-binding-variable-to-2-generated-bin)

Comment: View binding and data binding are totally different things, and almost exclusive of one another.  Those links won't help you.

Comment: Probably could you suggest me what should I do? Or maybe a good tutorial or explanation? It's the fourth day, since I can't make it work.